# unable to place order. Please try again later in magento 2.1 C E

Tags: magento2, error

Unable to **place order**. Please try again later in **Magento 2.1 C E**, till now it was working.

Comment: Please, explain more details about your issue - step by step reproduce it.

Comment: am not able to place order sir, POST http://dev.i3lsundial.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/fd49febdd610432892ebf99a3f0840aa/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)  , this error is getting in console. how can i fix .

Comment: http://dev.i3lsundial.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Check any error log?

Comment: can you please explain your problem in detail??

Comment: To get more idea about the error please visit below link:   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141366/magento-2-1-1-an-error-occured-on-the-server-please-try-again-at-checkout/170103#170103